# React Axios Http Call using Promise function

Tags: reactjs

I am using Axios Api to call Http function,

Here i have the following code to get the json data,

```
api.get("/",options).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data.message);
  console.log(response.data.response);
  window.input=response.data.response
  renderTableData()
})
```

and here is the one i am going to append the json,

```
const state = { 
students:window.input}
console.log(window.input);
  const renderTableData=()=> {
      return state.students.map((student, index) => {
         const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
         return (
            <tr key={id}>
               <th scope="row">
                      <Media className="align-items-center">
                        <a
                          className="avatar rounded-circle mr-3"
                          href="#pablo"
                          onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                        >
                          <img
                            alt="..."
                            src={
                              require("../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg")
                                .default
                            }
                          />
                        </a>
                        <Media>
                          <span className="mb-0 text-sm">{id}   </span>
                        </Media>
                      </Media>
                    </th>
                   
            </tr>
         )
      })
   }
```

My full code looks like

```
// reactstrap components
import {
  Badge,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  Media,
  Pagination,
  PaginationItem,
  PaginationLink,
  Table,
  Container,
  Row,
  UncontrolledTooltip,
} from "reactstrap";

import axios from "axios";
import data from "./data";
var apitoken= localStorage.getItem('apitoken');

const api=axios.create({baseURL:"https://109.249.277.245/testing/api/v1/account"})
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': apitoken}
}

**
api.get("/",options).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data.message);
  console.log(response.data.response);
  window.input=response.data.response
  renderTableData()
})
**
const state = { 
students:window.input}
console.log(window.input);
  const renderTableData=()=> {
      return state.students.map((student, index) => {
         const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
         return (
            <tr key={id}>
               <th scope="row">
                      <Media className="align-items-center">
                        <a
                          className="avatar rounded-circle mr-3"
                          href="#pablo"
                          onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                        >
                          <img
                            alt="..."
                            src={
                              require("../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg")
                                .default
                            }
                          />
                        </a>
                        <Media>
                          <span className="mb-0 text-sm">{id}   </span>
                        </Media>
                      </Media>
                    </th>
                   
            </tr>
         )
      })
   }
  
const Accounts = () => {

 
  return (
    <>

      <Header />
      {/* Page content */}
      <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
        {/* Table */}
        <Row>
          <div className="col">
            <Card className="shadow">
              <CardHeader className="border-0">
                <h3 className="mb-0">All Account</h3>
              </CardHeader>
              <div>
          
          
         </div>
              <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
                <thead className="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Account Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Account Owner</th>
                    {/* <th scope="col">Pincode</th> */}
                    <th scope="col" />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {renderTableData()}
                 
                </tbody>
              </Table>
              <CardFooter className="py-4">
               
              </CardFooter>
          
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Row>
       
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Accounts;
```

The issue is the component is rendering even before call the api and fetching the response, What i need is i need to call API response then need to render the component,

Can you please help me to archive this,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know about how to write asnychronous js using async/await or try catch blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix may be to do the following:

Simply put an if statement on the line above state.students.map() call to see if your students object exists and render based on that. Example: `if(state.students) {//your return statement} else {//render something else, possibly nothing}`

Another thing to note:

I think you’re using a functional component as a class component by having a state object; this should be a private data member within your class. You can test this yourself by using lifecycle methods, however it seems you may not be aware of how to use React hooks, judging by your code.

You should manage your state for the functional component using React Hooks, otherwise refactor this functional component into a Class component.

React uses two virtual DOMs to compare your ‘previous’ state to the ‘current’ state and uses the component lifecycle to assess whether there has been a change using the “===“ operator. In your case bc your state is outside of the functional component, there may be a missing reference and your state may not be tracked properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i need to get the response from API before rendering it

Comment: This wouldn’t render any data unless a response is present.